# how do I set up my sd card reader and USB flash drives?

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04.2, but can't figure out how mount my sd card reader and flash drives to transfer files.

I am New to this having used Windows since the beginning of time. I have figured most other problems I have come across but I am stumped with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most SD card readers, SD cards and flash drives are recognized by Ubuntu as soon as you plug them in. Most SD cards and flash drives are also automatically mounted by Ubuntu as soon as you plug them in. If the device is mounted, then an icon for that device will appear in the Launcher. To browse the folders and files on a device, just click on the device's icon in the Launcher.

It is also possible to easily safely remove a portable device if it is mounted similarly to the way you would do it in Windows using an application in the Ubuntu Software Center called *ejecter*. Ejecter is a simple menu that sits in the system notification area, providing you a quick way to unmount an external peripheral device such as USB flash drive, CD/DVD disk, external hard disk and so on. To safely remove a portable device click on the Ejector icon in the notification area, select the device that you want to safely remove from the Ejecter menu and then you will see a popup notification telling you that you can safely remove the portable device.

Alternatively if you don't want to install Ejecter you can simply right-click on the device in the default file manager and select "Safely Remove Drive" as shown.

**Update for Ubuntu 14.04**
You no longer need to install Ejecter in Ubuntu 14.04. Instead just right-click the portable device's icon in the Launcher and select *Safely remove*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am at a bit of a loss now I have tried lots of things. I know the pc recognises my media as could see it in terminal. But as you can see from picture my desktop is not picking it up. Is there something I need to change in my systems settings?

Answer (score 0):

I just got an external card reader for my Ubuntu machine and my stepdad gave me a tip, unplug the card reader from the computer, insert the card, then plug in the card reader and the memory card will mount. Try that and see if it works. I have yet to try it.

Hope this helps.